# Eigen values and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space V such that $dim(RangeT)=k$ , then how to prove  $T$ can have $at$ $most$ $k+1$ distinct eigen values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=n$ the assert is trivial.

If $k<n$, then $0$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $n-k$, so its algebraic multiplicity is at least $n-k$.

Therefore the sum of the algebraic multiplicities of the other eigenvalues is at most $k$, which makes for at most $k$ nonzero eigenvalues.

Let the eigenvalues be $\lambda_1=0,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_r$; then the characteristic polynomial is
$$
(\lambda_1-X)^{m_1}(\lambda_2-X)^{m_2}\dots(\lambda_r-X)^{m_r}
$$
with $m_1\ge n-k$ and $m_i\ge1$ for $i=2,\dots,r$. Since
$$
n=m_1+m_2+\dots+m_r\ge n-k+\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{r-1}=n-k+r-1
$$
we get $r\le k+1$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Shona Added the full argument

Comment: T:V→V so dimT(V)=dimV so by rank nullity theorem dimker(T)= 0 so T(v)=0 only for v=0 so one value is 0 and other are k values since dim(RangeT)=k so k+1 values .. so these are at most ???

Comment: @Shona Why should $\dim T(V)=\dim V$?

Comment: Since T is onto

Comment: @Shona Who says that? You're given that the image of $T$ has dimension $k$. If you're referring to the case $n=k$, then it's obvious: there are at most $n$ eigenvalues and $n<n+1=k+1$.

Comment: Given that T is a linear operator

Comment: @Shona The map $T\colon V\to V$ defined by $T(v)=0$ is a linear operator and $\dim T(V)=\dim V$ if and only if $\dim V=0$, which is usually not the case.

Comment: If k<n, then how is 0 is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity  n−k

Comment: @Shona By definition of geometric multiplicity and the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: @Shona The geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the dimension of the null space of $T-\lambda I$; in the case $\lambda=0$, it is the dimension of the null space of $T$; since the rank is, by assumption, $k$, the rank-nullity theorem gives that the geometric multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is $n-k$ (provided, of course, that $k<n$, so $0$ is actually an eigenvalue).

Comment: Can you pls explain this step
n=m1+m2+⋯+mr≥n−k+1+⋯+1r−1=n−k+r−1

Comment: @Shona The sum of the algebraic multiplicities is $n$; I then just sum all the inequalities $m_1\ge n-k$, $m_2\ge1,\dots,m_r\ge 1$ (and there are $r-1$ if the last type).

Comment: Ok thank you egreg for helping

Answer (score 2):

Hint: eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Comment: Yes i did that but dont get the $atmost$ part .. and i didnt use the dim(RangeT)=k . Is it connected to the atmost part ?

Comment: "At most", not "atmost".  Further hint: a eigenvector for a nonzero eigenvalue is in the range.

Comment: It means there are k distint eigen values for sure since dim(RangeT)=k ...

Comment: $ T : V \to V $ so dimT(V)=dimV so by rank nullity theorem dimker(T)= 0 so T(v)=0 only for v=0  so one value is 0 and other are k values since dim(RangeT)=k so k+1 values .. so these are at most ???

Comment: The eigenvectors for eigenvalues other than $0$ are in the range, which has dimension $k$.  That says there  can't be more than $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors for eigenvalues other than $0$.  Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, so there can't be more than $k$ distinct eigenvalues other than $0$.  Thus there can't be more than $k+1$ distinct eigenvalues (including possibly $0$).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining 